# Is the decay $B\rightarrow K^* \gamma$ decay allowed in the Standard Model?

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

This is my idea of the Feynman diagram of the $B^0$ to a $K^0$ decay:[image]

The photon is radiated off by one of the particles, and by $up$ quarks I just mean ($u$,$c$ and $t$) and their antiquarks.

how would I go on to calculate the amplitude for this decay, and how would I know if it is allowed in the Standard Model?

Comment: In general (particle) interactions have certain [conservation laws](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/parint.html) as compatibility conditions. So if these do not hold the interaction is not compatible with the standard model. Some of them are: baryon number, lepton number, color, charge, momentum etc... i would have to look a bit more throroughly to given a better answer..

Comment: Any two-W process is going to be weak-surpressed relative the dominate singly weak decays. Looking is the copy of the particle physics booklet on my desk I see some other double weak decay channels listed with branching ration limits in the $10^{-4}$--$10^{-6}$ range. The listed limit for decay to $K^0 l^+ l^-$ is $3 \times 10^{-7}$.

Comment: "suppressed". How do you quantify this?

Comment: The branching ratio quantifies it. Singly weak decays are much more common than doubly weak decays (by ratios of 10000:1 or more).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed. This is a typical flavor changing neutral process. In the Standard Model, this kind of process is highly suppressed, because the neutral bosons ($\gamma$, $Z$) always couple to quarks of the same flavor at tree-level. So, a vertex connecting two quarks of different flavors with a neutral gauge boson only appears at higher orders in perturbation theory.

For the process $B\to K \gamma$, there are two types of diagrams that may contribute: (i) box diagrams and (ii) penguin diagrams. The first type of diagram is already drawn in you question and you just have to be careful if you are considering $K^0$ or $\bar{K}^0$ in the final state, since this diagram changes flavor two times ($\Delta F =2$).

The second type of diagram is given by

$\hskip{5cm}$ [image: penguin diagram]

where the second quark is just a spectator and the $W$ boson and the $t$ quark are running in the loop. So, in this case you change flavor only 1 time ($\Delta F =1$). There are other diagrams similar to this one that are also called "penguin diagrams", because you can also exchange $W$ and $t$, or draw a self-energy like diagram.

Now, how do we compute this kind of diagram? Usually, we write an effective Hamiltonian with all allowed dimension 6 operators multiplying Wilson Coefficients. Then, we compute theses diagrams in the full theory (with propagating $W$ bosons) and we make the matching of the effective theory with the full theory, extracting the values of the Wilson coefficients. You can find more details in the [review of Buras](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9806471), for example.

---